# what is the name of this language / algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, function, structure, polynomials

[image]

this doesn't look like java/python/c/..etc

its from a book about algorithm/data structures

after a few searches i felt like this is called functional programming, but still
this **ADD/ZERO/ISZERO/for_loop_syntax** is different in it,

> so, what is this thing?, what do i call this type of writings?

> & where do i run it? *[if its a programming language]*

> is it wrong, if i write ADD(x,y) as SUM(x,y)?

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: That seems like just some sort of pseudo code, not an actual programming language. The book should introduce that at some point. The first part ("declare") declares a bunch of functions; the second part ("for") is _not_ a for-loop but defines the values/evaluation rules for all those function "for" different parameters. That bit is indeed written in the style of some functional languages. (In fact I would not rule out that it _is_ an actual programming language)

Comment: i don't remember its name, its about data structures and algorithms, it also had a structure/function for ARRAY  `CREATE()` creates an empty array. `RETRIEVE()` retrieve value from an array at the given index.  `STORE()` to add a new value to the given index on given array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a formal definition of a Polynomial as computer data structure.

Source is the Book *Fundamentals of Data Structures* by Ellis Horowitz and Sartaj Sahni. The language being used is called [SPARKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparks-language).

Introduction to the defintion from the book (page 47; Chapter 2: Arrays):
*The first step is to consider how to define polynomials as a
computer structure. For a mathematician a polynomial is a sum of terms where each term has the form `ax^e`; `x` is the variable, `a` is the coefficient and `e` is the exponent. However this is not an appropriate definition for our purposes. When defining a data object one must decide what functions will be
available, what their input is, what their output is and exactly what it is that they do. A complete specification of the data structure polynomial is now given.*

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284927/cheking-a-zero-polynomial).

Comment: bravo, nice find!